# response 405 when trying to upload timesheets to Xero using PyXero

Tags: python, python-3.x, xero-api

library = pyxero 0.9.1

Hey there,

I'm trying to automate the uploading of timesheets to Xero using Python but have hit a stumbling block.
I have no issue retrieving information using API but when I try to POST a new timesheet I get a 405 response code. I've tried to simplify my JSON data to the bare minimum Xero allows, but the error still persists. Sample code below

```
from xero import Xero
import configs
import datetime
from xero.auth import PrivateCredentials
credentials = PrivateCredentials(configss.key, configss.RSAstr)
xero = Xero(credentials)

employees = xero.payrollAPI.employees.all()

timesheets = {'timesheets': {'timesheet': {'EmployeeID': employees[0]["EmployeeID"],
              'StartDate': datetime.datetime(2018,8,15),
              'EndDate': datetime.datetime(2018,8,21),
              'Status': 'Draft'}}}

xero.payrollAPI.timesheets.put(timesheets)
```

Please note that I can post new contacts and invoices without a problem. 
Looking at my API call history from the app.xero.com site I see a message with

Request Message =

```
    <Timesheets><Timesheet><EmployeeID>38fcaf73-e35c-4f38-9ebe-642ef6d5b7c7</EmployeeID> 
<StartDate>2018-09-15</StartDate><EndDate>2018-09-21</EndDate> 
<Status>DRAFT</Status></Timesheet></Timesheets>
```

Response
405 - Method not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Your description says POST but your code says 'put' - the docs - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/payroll-api/timesheets - suggest that the method to use is POST.

If you switch your code to be 'post', does it have the desired effect?

Comment: You legend!! I was banging my head here and can't believe I missed that. xero.payrollAPI.timesheets.save(timesheets) did the trick!!